# How to search elasticsearch and count the lines/result by a value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a bunch of messages with a unique ID on each line (xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx). I would like to search and get a count of each unique message.

```
GET _count "OR" GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": {
        "query": "limit for"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
limit for AAA-AAA-AAA-AAA has 10 entries
limit for BBB-BBB-BBB-BBB has 30 entries
limit for CCC-CCC-CCC-CCC has 1000 entries
```

Comment: was your question answered, @rcmpayne?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (1) you don't want to create one query for each unique ID to count, (2) the `message` field contains always the information you are looking for (i.e., "limit for "), (3) the `message` field is of type `keyword`, then you can run the following aggregation:

```
GET name_of_your_index/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_message": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "message",
        "size": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where the size value 10000 is any number lower than the max expected number of unique message values.